# Asymmetric Filesystem Encryption

Tags: mount, filesystem, encryption, ecryptfs

How to encrypt (live) data preferrably as a write only filesystem using a rsa public key known on the device (which is offline), that only later can be decrypted by using the private key?
So once written the data cant be stolen even if an attacker gets his hands on the device.

eCryptFS doesnt seem to support such a one way use case.

Comment: Does it have to be public key encryption? Wouldn't a plain old secret passphrase work? Or a keyfile, that's encrypted with your gpg public/secret keypair? And what exactly's wrong with eCryptFS (or a LUKS partition/file)? If they're encrypted securely, an attacker can't read them, whether or not it's read only or writeable when mounted - you can't mount it without the key

Comment: FYI, public key encryption almost always uses conventional encryption of the actual data; only the conventional key is encrypted with the public/private keypair. Apparently conventional encryption is a LOT faster